# How do I attach CSS properties to the <body> tag?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to add `background-color: blue` to the body tag in my html document.

Unfortunately, it doesn't have an ID or a class and that's out of my control because of my use case.

I have access to my CSS style sheet and I can add anything that can normally go into a CSS Style sheet.

How do I attach a style attribute to the body tag from my css style sheet?

Comment: `body{ background-color: blue;}`

Comment: You can try to add `body { background-color: blue` }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
body{
background-color: blue
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an ID to apply stylesheets to a html Tag.
You can do it like on a class or ID just leave out the '#'/'.' `body{ background-color: blue }` it applies to all  Tags (obviously there only is one)

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can create a special class for your body element Like this, for example.

HTML:

```
<body class="bg-blue">
.....
.....
</body>
```

Css:

```
.bg-blue{
background-color: blue
}
```

Comment: _"Unfortunately, it doesn't have an ID or a class and that's out of my control because of my use case"_